# Extracting note data from a .mxl file using music21

Tags: python, list, music21

I am quite comfortable with python, but have recently gotten into trying some musical analysis. I have come across music21, and I would like to know how to extract the basic note data (pitch and duration) of every note in a musical .mxl file. I have gone through the documentation, but have struggled to digest it all and find something that does what I need. Due to my limited experience with .mxl files and music21 I cannot provide any real example of what I have tried so far.

However, what I have gathered is that one can get a plot of the music by using

```
s = converter.parse('exampleFile.mxl')
test=s.measures(1, 10)
test.plot('horizontalbar')
```

which, for the particular piece that i used, looks like

[mxl example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu161.png)

This clearly shows that in the first measure, the notes C4, Eb and G are played where the length of the bars represent the note duration. Ultimately I would like a this data in a list format.

By doing,

```
test=s.measures(1, 5)
test.show('text')
```

I can get a list of the notes played, with their beats in position in measure, but it comes in what is printed is something like

```
 {0.0} <music21.key.Key of E- major>
 {0.0} <music21.meter.TimeSignature 4/4>
 {0.0} <music21.note.Note C>
 {0.5} <music21.note.Note E->
 {1.0} <music21.note.Note G>
 {1.5} <music21.note.Note E->
 {2.0} <music21.note.Note C>
 {2.5} <music21.note.Note E->
 {3.0} <music21.note.Note G>
 {3.5} <music21.note.Note E->
```

But this still requires massaging to: 1) get the same information that the graph displays and 2), to get it into a list format that I would like.

Any help with this would be really appreciated. In the meanwhile I will continue to read the documentation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Luca -- I'd suggest just working through the User's Guide chapter by chapter--since you have a lot of Python already there are some things you can skip in chapters 2-5 but they're give the basis for how to deal with streams as lists of lists.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably after something like this:

```py
for tN in s.recurse().notes:
    print([tN.step,tN.octave,tN.duration.quarterLength])
```